# Remove div with beautiful animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to remove `div` with a great animation but I don't know how to do this.

So I make that [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dzk13nym/) for example :

### HTML

```
<h2>What I have</h2>
<div class='test'>1</div>
<div class='test'>2</div>
<div class='test'>3</div>
<div class='test'>4</div>
<div class='test'>5</div>

<h2>What I Want</h2>
<div class='test2'>1</div>
<div class='test2'>2</div>
<div class='test2'>3</div>
<div class='test2'>4</div>
<div class='test2'>5</div>
```

### CSS

```
div.test, div.test2 {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    margin:5px;

    border:1px solid black;

    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}
```

### JS

```
$('div.test').on('click', function() {
   $(this).remove();
});

$('div.test2').on('click', function() {
    // I don't want to change opacity or padding...
    // I just want to remove with animation like this:
    $(this).css('width','0px').css('padding','0px');
    $(this).css('opacity',0);
});
```

I see a good example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/88Cw4/1/)

But when a div is removed, she's cut and they are only animation for the next div.

Any idea ?

### EDIT

Finally resolved : [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dzk13nym/1/)

Comment: You can answer your own question.  You don't have to edit the question with your solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've solved my problem with `animation` [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dzk13nym/1/)

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 11):

Since you remove your `element`, it cannot be `animated` anymore. You could animate via a class and on `transitionend` remove the element. Like this for example:

```
.animate
{
    height: 0px;//or anything you need
    transition: height 1s;
}



$('#delete').click(function (e) {
        //instead of remove you add a class.
        $(".notification:first-child").addClass('animate');
    });
$('.notification').on('transitionend', function(e){
    //when transition is finished you remove the element.
    $(e.target).remove()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nawkufh1/

Answer (score 6):

You could do it like this:

```js
$('#delete').click(function (e) {
  $(".notification:first-child").slideUp(function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});

$('#add').click(function (e) {
  $(".notifications").append("<div class='notification'></div>");
});
```

```css
.notifications {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px green;
}

.notification {
    height: 40px;
    background: lightblue;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="delete">delete</button>
<button type="button" id="add">add</button>
<div class="notifications">
  <div class="notification"></div>
  <div class="notification"></div>
  <div class="notification"></div>
  <div class="notification"></div>
</div>
```

This uses jQuery to animate instead of CSS. When the delete button is clicked, it slides the top bar up then it gets removed.